# BigCommerce customer attributes from client/store

Tags: bigcommerce

Can I retrieve the customer's

There is a current-customer API - https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/customers/current-customer-api, but it only returns the following bits about a customer.

```
"customer": {
   "id": 4927,
   "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
   "group_id": "6"
}
```

I'd really to have the ability to get all the data from 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/customer-subscribers/v3-customers-api/customer-attributes/customersattributesget as a property of the payload for current-customer-api

`/customer/current.jwt?app_client_id={appClientId}&attribute-ids:in=1,2,3`

```
"customer": {
   "id": 4927,
   "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
   "group_id": "6"
   "attributes": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Age",
          "type": "string",
          "date_created": "2018-11-13T21:42:06Z",
          "date_modified": "2018-11-14T16:46:23Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Shoe Size",
          "type": "number",
          "date_created": "2018-11-14T16:34:57Z",
          "date_modified": "2018-11-14T16:34:57Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Date Joined",
          "type": "date",
          "date_created": "2019-02-19T19:13:21Z",
          "date_modified": "2019-02-19T19:13:21Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting feature request. The purpose of the current customer API is to verify the identity of a logged in customer in a secure way, which is why the payload is so minimal (with the understanding that you would likely be making a request for the full customer record based on the id returned).

We are planning to surface customer attribute data on the storefront though, which sounds like it would solve for your use case. We'll be adding Handlebars support soon, and we've got a storefront GraphQL API in the works as well. You can read more in our blog post here:

https://medium.com/bigcommerce-developer-blog/customize-and-extend-your-customer-data-with-the-new-bigcommerce-v3-customers-api-8609903e102a

Comment: yes, getting the customer attribute data (and potentially the customer-form-fields) would be EXACTLY what I need, either via REST or GraphQL.